# What does the `|` mean in a single case DU?

Tags: f#

Consider this DU:

```ml
type Foo = | Foo
```

My understanding was that this is equivalent:

```ml
type Foo = Foo
```

However, if we introduce generics they are not:

```ml
// Does not compile
type Bar<'t> = Bar
```

```ml
// Compiles
type Bar<'t> = | Bar
```

What's going on here?

---

More discoveries:

```
// Works
type Bar<'t> = Bar of 't
```

```
// Works
type Bar<'t> = | Bar of 't
```

Comment: First is type alias, second is single-case DU

Comment: Interesting. If you don't mind posting a longer answer - how is it possible to have a type alias onto itself?

Comment: As I started [playing with decompiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzgHwG0AeAOQgFEBHAVwEMMBLAFwE8BuAAnIGEIBbAA50ojXBAB2APgC6nAPTzOsACY0wMThIhjNjCZwg1mg4wFgAUG0GaAYhAicAvJ3sQgA=) things began to be strange. `type Foo = Foo` is DU, `type Foo = Bar` is type alias, `type Foo<'a> = Foo` is forbidden, `type Foo<'a> = Bar` is DU. Ambiguity resolution scares me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two interesting cases here. The first one is:

```
type Foo = Foo
```

This looks like a self-referential type alias at first, but that's not allowed, so the compiler instead accepts it as a valid DU. This is correct, although subtle, behavior.

The second interesting case is:

```
type Bar<'t> = Bar   // Error: The type 'Bar<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0
```

This also looks like a self-referential type alias at first, but with the wrong number of type parameters. Since the reference is invalid, the compiler issues an error before it has a chance to realize that it's actually looking at a valid DU definition. I think one could reasonably argue that this is a bug in the compiler, and I suggest submitting it as an issue to the F# compiler team. The expected behavior is that this is a valid DU, just like `type Foo = Foo` and `type Bar<'t> = | Bar`.

Note also that the following is (correctly) not allowed:

```ml
type Bar<'t> = Bar<'t>   // Error: This type definition involves an immediate cyclic reference through an abbreviation
```

---

The [compiler source-code](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/d0baa9a5762a74209d7943d680ae062c2e4ded44/src/Compiler/Checking/CheckDeclarations.fs#L4044) has the following to say:

```ml
// This unfortunate case deals with "type x = A" 
// In F# this only defines a new type if A is not in scope 
// as a type constructor, or if the form type A = A is used. 
// "type x = | A" can always be used instead.
```

Comment: nice, i couldnt work that one out...such are the problems caused by overloading the word type to mean 2 different things.